# javascript create class event

Tags: javascript, class

How do I create a custom event for a javascript class? 
**Example Code**

```
function somefunction(url){
   this.h_world = function(){/*some random code to do*/ };
}

var hw = new somefunction();
```

Now, for  a very simple example, how do I create a custom event handler for this when `hw.h_world` has finished executing and return some data with it?

**For example**

```
var hw = new somefunction();
hw.h_world();
hw.finished_h_world = function(somedata){
  alert(somedata);
}
```

Comment: No events are generated by the simple execution of JavaScript code (outside of some special behavior in Firefox around property "watch" settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass a callback function to h_world function and execute it on finish of it

```
function somefunction(url){
   this.h_world = function(cb){
      //do some operation
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') {
         cb();
         //cb.call(this, args1, arg2...); //execute callback in scope of current object
      }
   };
}
```

or you can add a function to your class like this

```
function somefunction(url){
   this.h_world = function(){
      //do operation
      this.h_world_finish(parameters);   
   };
   this.h_world_finish = function () {};
}

var obj = new someFunction(url);
obj.h_world_finish = function (arg) {
    alert("finished h_world");
};
obj.h_world();
```

Comment: That achieved what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: How is this diff... forget it.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a callback function:

```
function somefunction(url){
   this.h_world = function(callback){
      var somedata = 'some data';
      callback(somedata);
   };
}
```

And then:

```
var hw = new somefunction();
hw.h_world(function(somedata){
    alert(somedata); // Will alert 'some data';
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/xzeEd/