# JavaScript custom events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to trigger event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)
> [JavaScript custom Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671995/javascript-custom-event-listener)

I have created new custom event this way:

```
window.addEventListener('customEvent', function () { doSomethingOnEvent(); }, false);
```

How can I trigger this kind of custom event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671995/javascript-custom-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

You must init the event first:

```
var myCustomEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
myCustomEvent.initEvent("customEvent",true,true);
```

And then to trigger it:

```
document.dispatchEvent(myCustomEvent);
```