# How Observable pattern works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can easily understand how it works in C#, but in Javascript I'm a little bit confused. Here is a little test code I wrote:

```
  function Lunch(name,price)
  {     
    var priceChanging = [], priceChanged = [];

    this.name = function(val)
    {
        return name;
    }
    this.price = function(val)
    {
        if(val !== price && val !== undefined )
         {
            for(var i = 0; i < priceChanging.length; i++)
            {
                if(!priceChanging[i](this,val))
                {
                    return price;
                }                   
            }
            price = val;
            for(var i = 0; i < priceChanged.length; i++)            
              { 
                priceChanged[i](this);
              }     
         }
        return price;
    }

    this.OnPriceChanging = function(val)    
    {
         priceChanging.push(val);
    }
    this.OnPriceChanged = function(val)     
    {
         priceChanged.push(val);
    }
 }

var order = new Lunch("Fish and Chips",20);

console.log(order.name());
console.log(order.price());

order.OnPriceChanging(function(name,price)
{
    if(price > 30)
    {
        console.log("Price too high");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

});

order.OnPriceChanged(function(name)
{
    console.log("Price changed to: $" + name.price());
});
```

It runs fine, the thing is I want to be able to explain it to myself. I'm not in front of a debugger and just used Notepad at the moment. I just thought of it like .NET where subscribers are put in a container, I'm just curious how it works in Javascript.

Does the OnPriceChanging and OnPriceChanged function call themselves automatically anytime you add/change the price? I guess I'm just uncomfortable with how Javascript is loosely typed and all.

As always, I'm very thankful for all the imparted knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript custom Event Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671995/javascript-custom-event-listener)

Answer (score 2):

It's really quite simple. You have two arrays that store functions:

```
var priceChanging = [], priceChanged = [];
```

You have two methods that push functions into the arrays:

```
this.OnPriceChanging = function(val)    
{
     priceChanging.push(val);
}
this.OnPriceChanged = function(val)     
{
     priceChanged.push(val);
}
```

You then push functions into the arrays:

```
order.OnPriceChanging(function(name,price)
{
    if(price > 30)
    {
        console.log("Price too high");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

order.OnPriceChanged(function(name)
{
    console.log("Price changed to: $" + name.price());
});
```

Note that the code above may be confusing if you're not used to seeing anonymous functions. They are exactly equivalent to this:

```
function priceChangingCallback (name,price)
{
    if(price > 30)
    {
        console.log("Price too high");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function priceChangedCallback (name)
{
    console.log("Price changed to: $" + name.price());
})

order.OnPriceChanging(priceChangingCallback);
order.OnPriceChanged(priceChangedCallback);
```

So you see, the arrays `priceChanging` and `priceChanged` should now both contain a single function each.

> Does the OnPriceChanging and OnPriceChanged function call themselves automatically anytime you add/change the price?

No, they do not. In fact to be precise, it's not `OnPriceChanging` and `OnPriceChanged` that are called. It's functions inside the arrays `priceChanging` and `priceChanged`. And they don't call themselves. You called them:

```
this.price = function(val)
{
    if(val !== price && val !== undefined )
     {
        for(var i = 0; i < priceChanging.length; i++)
        {
            if(!priceChanging[i](this,val)) // <--- you're calling it here!!
            {
                return price;
            }                   
        }
        price = val;
        for(var i = 0; i < priceChanged.length; i++)            
          { 
            priceChanged[i](this); // <-- you're calling it here!!
          }     
     }
    return price;
}
```

You're calling all functions inside `priceChanging` and `priceChanged` arrays inside for loops. Functions that you added to the arrays using the `OnPriceChanging` and `OnPriceChanged` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's confusing me is I only called those once, yet when I put order.price() for x number of times, those functions get called again? without me explicitly calling it.

Comment: What do you mean by "those"? Like I mentioned above, you aren't calling the functions once, you're calling them inside the for loops inside the `price` method. So every time you call `price()` you also call `priceChanged[i](this)`

Comment: The thing to get used to is that functions are also objects that can be treated like variables. I'm not sure about C# but this is a normal language feature in most languages these days.

Comment: I see.. It was the absence of those names and types that I'm used to in C# that's confusing..thanks again!