# Javascript to React communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this peace of vanilla js code that needs to notify a React component for a certain event. How to do it?

Please note, I do not want to read about Flux/Redux, Thinking in Components, etc. I just want a plain and simple one-liner for communication between Javascript code  and React. Probably I am looking for some kind of pub/sub pattern without relying on another 3rd party library.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10085161/320125)

Javascript side:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent("myEvent",true,true);
evt.foo = "bar";
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

React side:

```
document.addEventListener("myEvent",myEventHandler,false);
```